# CSS Top Does Not Work With Links

Tags: html, css

When I try to use the **top** word in CSS on a link it does not work.
I want my links to be lower on the page so I would use **top: 10%;**. That does not work though because my links seem to not move no matter what. I can however get them to move sideways with **text-align:center;**.

My HTML

```
<div id="pythonfilelistfiles">
    <a href="http://localhost/project1/pythonfiles-calcuator.html">
        <div class="pythonfilelistboxs" id="file1">
            <h1> Simple Calculator </h1>
        </div>
    </a>
```

My CSS

```
#pythonfilelistfiles {
    width: 78%;
    height: 92%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: -2%;
    max-width: 78%;
    max-height: 92%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#file1 {
    top: 0%;
}

.pythonfilelistboxs {
    width: 96%;
    height: 12%;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: 2%;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 80%;
}
```

Comment: You need to have them positioned absolutely, not relatively in order to use the 'top' code. Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/pg6VC/

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you could accomplish this, most of which are probably a little more maintainable than using positioning properties -

- Add padding to the top of the containing div.
- Increase the `line-height` for those links.
- Use `margin-top` to move it down a relative amount (you'll need to set it to `display: block` as well, which will change how they behave in the page flow).

It is probably easier to use a unit other than percentages in any case - it would better practice to use a type-related unit like `em` or `rem`.

Comment: #file1 {margin-top:10%;}